# Content Security Policy issue on newly created asp.net mvc project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, content-security-policy

I created a new web project via MVC5 (MVC, WebAPI, no authentication, not configured for HTTPS or Docker) targeting framework 4.6.1. I haven't performed any changes or modification.

I run the web app and check Chrome's developer tools console and notice the error

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-dLJqJSO80JC9QgrIRU3rSxbpAb/bYXylIngicy7GOgY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution

I haven't done anything since it was all default and newly created project.

I'm using VS 2019 community edition.

What seems to be the issue and how to fix the content security policy issue?

Comment: Interested to understand why you're using such an old version of the .Net framework and MVC itself for a brand new project?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't done any study action for the latest framework and core.

Comment: I would suggest your time would be better spent doing that.

Comment: It's likely that any issue that affects a *new* MVC5 project will also affect a *new* NetCore project.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of my project issue. It was the chrome plugin "Blaze meter" that causes the Content Security Policy to trigger and project the error on the console prompt. When i turn it off, project went well and working normally.